# Rotate rectangle by dragging icon

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a rectangle, that I need to rotate about itself, by dragging the icon in the top right corner. Now I have 2 versions of code, both of this doesn't work almost as it should, and I can't figure out what's wrong with second version. The question is, how I should change code to make a rectangle rotate with an icon on it?

```
  struct rotateTest: View {
    @State var angle: Angle = .zero
    @State var recSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 80)
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .frame(width: recSize.width, height: recSize.height)
//            .rotationEffect(angle) //v1 if rotation effect applyed here, rectangle rotate as it should, but rotation icon dont move with it (pic. 1)
            .overlay(
                Image(systemName: "arrow.counterclockwise.circle.fill")
                    .offset(x: recSize.width / 2, y: -recSize.height / 2)
                    .gesture(DragGesture()
                                .onChanged{ value in
                                    angle = calcRotationAngle(value.translation)
                                })
            )
            .rotationEffect(angle) //v2 if rotation effect applyed here, icon move with rectangle, but rotation become unpredictable (pic. 2)
        
    }
    func calcRotationAngle(_ translation: CGSize) -> Angle {
        Angle(radians: Double(
                atan2(translation.height - recSize.height / 2,
                      translation.width + recSize.width / 2 )))
    }
}
```

pic. 1:
[image]

pic. 2:
[image]